# bones auto wieght painting randomly on opposite side

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

auto weight painting randomly selects finger on opposite side

[image: auto weight painting randomly selects finger on opposite side]

ive tried geting rid of all the weight info and bone modifiers on all the objects (every limb is a diferent object) and and re shuffled the bone placements mutiple times. lastly i tried weight painting by hand but shift ctrl LMB didnt select the bones for some reason. cant find resources for weight painting on multiple objects. any help would be apreciated

Here is the file
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: There is an error in the naming of the ring finger. I will provide a full answer shortly.

Comment: do you have a reason why you don't join all the parts together? Or if you don't want any deformation you can simply parent each part to each bone, without Armature Deform

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have occurred because the mesh was parented before the mirror modifier was applied, causing the ring finger to follow the other hand.
To resolve the naming problem, delete half of the armature and symmetrize it.
Then, re-parent the mesh to the armature with new weights, either automatically or manually.